# Runas command path issue

Tags: cmd, registry

Hi I am trying to run SQL as a user from a command so I can put it in the context menu but ssms opens with "Cannot find x file". My best guess is that the spaces are causing a problem since normally running this would expect `ssms.exe "\\remote\1. folder\has spaces.sql"` to ignore the spaces but `runas` requires both the program and file be within the same double quotes.

This is the command I need:

```
runas /provile /env /user:domain\username "ssms.exe \\remote\1. folder\has spaces.sql"
```

The following command of course runs fine:

```
runas /provile /env /user:domain\username "ssms.exe c:\a\tmp\s.sql"
```

I do not have the option of renaming the folders or files but I regularly need to run queries as a different user. Is there a way I can escape the spaces or layer up double quotes somehow?

Thanks

EDIT:
As I am using the context menu, I am passing the above command with %1 instead of the actual file path in the registry and the command window closes too fast for me to see the error but the following command is not working. I have a feeling it is a pathing issue still but I cannot actually prove that but any help would be appreciated.

```
runas /provile /env /user:domain\username "ssms.exe \"%1""
```

( With %1 being `\\remote\1. folder\has spaces.sql` )

Comment: Have you tried `runas /provile /env /user:domain\username "ssms.exe \"\\remote\1. folder\has spaces.sql\""`?

Comment: @aschipfl holy moly that worked. Could you explain why; does the preceding \ stop the quotes marking the end of the quoted section that `runas` needs? I made an edit also, if you could help

Comment: When you type `runas /?` into a command prompt window, an example appears where the escaping method of quotation marks (`\"`) is used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape character `\` per aschipfl's comment.